# How can I use flexbox to create a masonry layout?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a masonry layout using flexboxes but I can't find a way to fill the gaps.

I attached a code pen example below

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpgMKX?editors=110

```
.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}
```

**Update:**

Please note that flex-direction: column will not work for me as it breaks the order of the content.

Comment: [Google](http://demosthenes.info/blog/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox)

Comment: I have seen this example but it uses a flex-direction of column rather then row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpwwpX

I made two more wrappers, one that is for the two boxes on the left and one that surrounds the two wrappers. Like this:

```
<div class="big-wrapper">
<div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="box oneTwo"></div>
    <div class="box oneOne"></div>
  </div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box oneOne"></div>
  <div class="box oneOne"></div>
  <div class="box twoOne"></div>
  <div class="box oneTwo"></div>
  <div class="box threes"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS I just added the two new wrappers adjusted their widths a bit, but you can play with that of course.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this approach will not scale and kind of defeat the purpose of using flexbox.